# DFT Matlab function

Tags: image, matlab, dft, spectrum

I've write a function that calculates the DFT of an image, My prupose is to show the amplitude spectrum without using the fftshift command. DFT_img.m looks like this:

```
function f = DFT_img(a);
  [n m]=size(a);
  for i =1:n
    k=1;
    for j =1:n
      l=1;
      F(i,j)=(1/n*n)*a(i,j)*exp(-i*2*pi*(k*i+l*j)/n);
      l=l+1;
    end
    k=k+1;
  end
  f=F;
```

And when i write in Command Window the commands

```
A = imread("lena.tiff");
ans = DFT_img(A);
spectrum = log(abs(ans));
mesh(spectrum)
```

i am not getting the same result that

> fftshift matlab function

does !!!
Am i having a mistake in the function, or where is the problem with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not a 2D DFT, at all.

The easiest way to write a 2D DFT is to perform a 1D DFT on each of the columns, and then perform a 1D DFT on each of the rows of the results.

In pseudocode:

```
temp = zeros(size(a));
f = zeros(size(a));

for i = (1:m)
    temp(:,i) = dft(a(:,i));
end

for j = (1:n)
    f(j,:) = dft(temp(j,:));
end
```

Comment: i dont understand!! What is "dft" in this case

Comment: It is showing me an Error !!!

Undefined function 'dft' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in DFT_img2 (line 6)
    temp(:,i) = dft(a(:,i));

Comment: @user2287999: Yes, it's **pseudocode**!  You will need to implement a function called `dft`.

Comment: My task is to use this formula F(i,j)=(1/n*n)*a(i,j)*exp(-i*2*pi*(k*i+l*j)/n); to perform DFT in the image that i created in this way:

<code>
% draw a square in the middle of image
% m - height of image
% n - width of image
% k - dimension of square
function f = Kat(m,n,k)
A = zeros(m,n);
A(m/2-k:m/2+k,n/2-k:n/2+k)=1;
f=A;
end

Comment: @user2287999: That formula is incorrect.  It should be `F(k,l) = ...`.

Comment: when i wrote in that way, the mesh command it is showing me this error
Error using mesh (line 76)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

'code'
A = Kat(512,512,32);
pergj=DFT_img(A);
spectrum = log(abs(pergj));
mesh(spectrum)
'code'

this is my Command Windows looks like !!!

Comment: @user2287999: I think you will need to spend some time researching what a 2D DFT actually does.  Until you understand that, it's somewhat hard for me to explain to you how to write the code ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look like DFT, and has some issues with index numbers: note that the DFT is defined as a sum of complex exponentials from 0:N-1, not from 1:N like in your code. Long story short: try this function (paste in a kmv_dft2.m file):

```
function F =  kmv_dft2(f)

[M, N] = size(f);
F = zeros(M,N);

for k = 0:M-1
    for l = 0:N-1
        F(k+1,l+1) = dft_atomic_sum(f,k,l,M,N);
    end
end

%% computing a core of DFT2
function F_kl = dft_atomic_sum(f,k,l,M,N)

F_kl = 0;

for m=0:M-1
    for n=0:N-1
        F_kl = F_kl + f(m+1,n+1)*exp(-i*2*pi*( k*m/M   + l*n/N) );        
    end
end
```

Now check this and compare with MATLAB FFT implementation

```
%%% input 2D signal
f = magic(5) 

%% Fast Fourier Transform
F_fft = fftshift(fft2(f))

%% Slow Discrete Fouriers Transform
F =  fftshift(kmv_dft2(f))
```

You may want to consult MATLAB help about `fftshift` function and what does it exactly do. This `fftshift` function is a source of constant confusion among novices, and [I even wrote a short explanation](http://www.mvkonnik.info/2014/06/fft-ifft-and-why-do-we-need-fftshift.html) for my own students about this.